# Find child with a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write code to search all children for a div that has a specific class.  The DIV does not have an ID.  Here is the HTML I will be using.

```
<div class="outerBUBGDiv">
<div class="innerBUBGDiv">
<div class="bgHeaderH2">Technology Group</div>
<div class="bgBodyDiv">
<div align="center">
<img height="33" border="0" width="180" src="/heading.jpg"/>
  /////other stuff here/////
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

How can I get the text inside the div with the class bgHeaderH2?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain this properly.  my $(this) is the parentof all the children above, an outer div.  I need to find which of the children has a class of bgHeaderH2.  So I need to do $(this).something

Comment: See my revised answer below...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Based on your comment, moddify this:

```
$( '.bgHeaderH2' ).html (); // will return whatever is inside the DIV
```

to:

```
$( '.bgHeaderH2', $( this ) ).html (); // will return whatever is inside the DIV
```

More about selectors: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: You should always use a class selector so 'div.bgHeaderH2' or there will be a performance penalty see http://www.componenthouse.com/article-19

Comment: @Dave: great tip! didn't event think of that as I was writing this :)

Comment: This answer is really "find any element in the page with a specific class."

Ryan's answer is more appropriate for the problem of finding the children of a certain div with a specific class.

Comment: @DaveAnderson your link is broken, and I am interested in why it's a performance hit

Comment: @camdixon here is that article https://componenthouse.com/tag/jquery/ but since my comment 7+ years ago a lot has changed and selectors have been well optimised. Here are a couple of links to check out that are more current instead; [Selector for best performance in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34100117/371), [Optimise Selectors](https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/)

Answer (score 67):

```
$(this).find(".bgHeaderH2").html();
```

or

```
$(this).find(".bgHeaderH2").text();
```

Comment: Thanks for the update Ryan, this works as does the other suggestion by Jan.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand your question properly, but it shouldn't matter if this div is a child of some other div. You can simply get text from all divs with class bgHeaderH2 by using following code:

```
$(".bgHeaderH2").text();
```