# Selector for best performance in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I just spent 2 hours reading online guides and blogs about jQuery selectors. Everybody says different things and every last one of them seem to be so sure. I need an expert opinion from Stackoverflow.

```
$(' #my-id div.my-class ')

$(' #my-id .my-class ')

$(' div.my-class ')

$(' .my-class ')


<div id="my-id">
    <div class="..">
        <div class=".."> Awesome stuff! </div>
        <div class="my-class">
            <p> I like carrots! </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which is the best selector in your opinion? I also need a short explanation because rewriting thousands of lines of code is at stake. *It happens one way or another, I just don't want to do it twice*.

Also, if I wanted to get `<p>`, should I give it a class because jQuery and CSS reads selectors from right to left?

Is there even such thing as too many classes or is it because people are just lazy?

---

If the same rules apply to CSS, just let me know. One word is enough.

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048  will help you to know about selectors .. If you need more information after you read this just let me know

Comment: I know the selectors, symbols and everything that comes with that. I just need to know what is most efficient way to select? I learned that some cases takes x TIMES more time than others depending what selectors you use. There is information about which is what but the problem is that these "opinions" are very different. I need a last advice from Stackoverflow community before I start rewriting huge amount of code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If all you want is all instances of DOM elements that match `.my-class`, then I see no reason why you should use anything other than:

```
$('.my-class')
```

The others are all more specific selectors and can be used if you want to narrow the selector to more than just `$('.my-class')`.

If you're really trying to fully optimize performance, than using jQuery in the first place is likely not the desired choice as the overhead of jQuery initialization and jQuery objects tends to slow things down.  You use jQuery because it's quick to code and offers great cross-browser support and a bunch of useful methods.  You don't use jQuery to optimize performance.

If you really want to compare the performance of your four jQuery options, then you will have to design up a representative set of HTML (which has to include lots of other things to be truly representative of a real world situation) and then test each of your selectors in some benchmarking tool like jsperf and run that test in all browsers that you care about and with the versions of jQuery that you will be using and then see if you can come to some particular conclusion.

This smells like an attempt at premature optimization.  Write your code first as simply as possible and only spend time optimizing performance when you've actually measured that you have a performance issue and that this is the place in your code where the performance bottleneck is.  99.99% of the time, the performance of a particular selector is not going to make one iota of difference in your code.  Code simply and without complication first.  In the 0.01% of the time that you actually want to optimize your code, you will probably care so much about performance that you will either pre-cache the list of elements or you will not code it in jQuery in order to avoid the jQuery object setup and overhead.

Here's a jsPerf: http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-comparison-specificity/4.  This shows relatively little difference between the options when tested in the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox and IE.  There is a slight bias in favor of the `$('.my-class')` option.

And for reference, you will find that:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("my-class")
```

**is as much as 50x faster than any of the jQuery options.**

Here's a screenshot of the jsperf results in Chrome:

[image]

### Conclusions

1. For normal coding where you haven't proven you actually have a performance issue that you need to spend time optimizing, use the simplest selector that meets your selection objective.
2. If it's really performance critical, use plain Javascript, not jQuery.

Comment: I added a comparison to `document.getElementsByClassName("my-class")`.

Comment: anything will be less performant that plainjs, if you need the maximum performance, go that way. Of course, you will have to deal with browser-compatibility functions, that's why this is something you should do only after you have proven with tests that you need extra performance

Answer (score 7):

According to [jQuery's Docs:](https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/)

> Beginning your selector with an ID is always best.

```
// Fast:
$( "#container div.robotarm" );

// Super-fast:
$( "#container" ).find( "div.robotarm" );
```

> Be specific on the right-hand side of your selector, and less specific
>   on the left.

```
// Unoptimized:
$( "div.data .gonzalez" );

// Optimized:
$( ".data td.gonzalez" );
```

> Avoid Excessive Specificity

```
$( ".data table.attendees td.gonzalez" );

// Better: Drop the middle if possible.
$( ".data td.gonzalez" );
```

> Avoid the Universal Selector.  Selections that specify or imply that a
>   match could be found anywhere can be very slow.

```
$( ".buttons > *" ); // Extremely expensive.
$( ".buttons" ).children(); // Much better.

$( ".category :radio" ); // Implied universal selection.
$( ".category *:radio" ); // Same thing, explicit now.
$( ".category input:radio" ); // Much better.
```

---

**Now, with all that said...**

It's good to be mindful of this stuff and to optimize where possible, but realistically many of these will, more or less, end up being micro optimizations. If you're looking to trim fat for a performance boost there are probably better places to look.

<sub><sub>Go ahead... Burn me as a heretic... I'm not scared...</sub></sub>

Comment: Don't go only by what you read.  If performance is important to you, then you have to measure your specific situation to decide what is best.  My tests don't show that beginning with an id actually improves things in any meaningful way.  So, why complicate your selector with no meaningful benefit.

Comment: @jfriend00 jsPerf crashed when I tried to check your result, did you notice any significant difference between the various jQuery selectors?

Comment: @jfriend00  I understand what you're saying though it is generally better to benchmark your own specific use case, but I figured the general guidance with a "don't waste your time" side note was worthwhile...

Comment: I added a screen shot to my answer of the results in Chrome.  As I said in the text of my answer, not much of a difference between the four methods the OP proposed.  But, `document.getElementsByClassName()` is way, way faster.  So if you want speed, get rid of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I did a benchmark test that show me it's better to choose more specific selectors.

I tested this HTML :

```
<div id="my-id">
    <div class="grand">
        <div class="parent"> Awesome stuff! </div>
        <div class="my-class">
            <p> I like carrots! </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js'></script>
```

With 8 different selectors :

```
$(' div#my-id div.grand div.parent div.my-class ').css("background-color", "#cccccc"); //case-1
$(' #my-id .grand .parent div.my-class ').css("background-color", "#cccccc"); //case-2
$(' #my-id .grand .parent .my-class ').css("background-color", "#cccccc"); //case-3
$(' div#my-id div.my-class ').css("background-color", "#cccccc"); //case-4
$(' #my-id div.my-class ').css("background-color", "#cccccc"); //case-5
$(' #my-id .my-class ').css("background-color", "#cccccc"); //case-6
$(' div.my-class ').css("background-color", "#cccccc"); //case-7
$(' .my-class ').css("background-color", "#cccccc"); //case-8
```

And results showed me that `case-1`, `case-2` and `case-3` are better than the others. you can see the result [here](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/ShowResult/29297).

Comment: Your test is flawed. The first three cases are looking for `.my-class` inside of `.parent`, which doesn't exist. Case 8 is actually the fastest successful test.