# CSS/jQuery performance - Is it better to provide higher resolution selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

Say I'm selecting a DOM element using CSS or jQuery, is it faster to provide a higher resolution?

That is, I'm trying to figure out which one of the following jquery selector methods is the best in terms of speed:

```
Method 1. $("#name")
Method 2. $("input#name")
Method 3. $("div input#name")
```

Or these CSS selectors:

```
Method 1. #name {font-weight: bold;}
Method 2. input#name {font-weight: bold;}
Method 3. div input#name {font-weight: bold;}
```

It seem like `Method 3` might make the selector's job easy since it can narrow down to the element faster?

Comment: possible duplicated question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34100018/selector-for-best-performance-in-jquery

Comment: it's depend on the case you use. Since jQuery is a library, you can ignore this part.

Comment: @ChrisChen the question you linked is about order of CSS selectors, my question is whether one method is more optimized than the other.

Comment: @NitinNain, I believe the performance was the main discussion point on that question. As per answer provided by jfriend00, the shortest jQuery selector is the fastest while vanilla js still beat them all.

Comment: Ah you're right. Sorry I was looking at another question that was also showing up as possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105736/what-is-the-order-of-precedence-for-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering these jQuery statements

```
Method 1. $("#name")
Method 2. $("input#name")
Method 3. $("div input#name")
```

all the three statements are equally good since `id` always need to be an unique value. So `$("#name")` is same as `$("div input#name")` unless dom have multiple field with same id

Now considering the css lines, it depends on the specificity.

```css
#name { color: red; }
input#name { color: yellow; }
div input#name { color: green; }
```

```html
<div>
  <input id='name'>
</div>
```

Comment: According to your snippet, the more precise the selector is faster. I thought at first you were just overriding the style with each new statement, but if you move `#name { color: red; }` to the last position, it still will be green showing. If you remove the green selector completely, then yellow will be showing.

Comment: `Faster` may not be actually mean anything here , but `Specificity` is more regarderd term. Here color `green` is overriding because the style is more specific as the input is inside a `div` element

Comment: Ah! It's my lack of vocabulary in english that made me misinterpret your answer. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the smaller the selector better the performance. I vaguely remember reading somewhere that the selectors are evaluated from right to left. So, the last sub-selector is evaluated first and the resulting list will then be condensed as it moves left. If you are worried about a certain instance you can always check the performance of that particular instance by measuring the time between before and after of either `querySelctorAll()` or `$()` by passing the possible selectors and see it yourself.