# Fastest possible way in jQuery to filter "Radios + Select + Checkbox" together simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the fastest strategy (in terms of Performance) to filter a combination of different type filters in jQuery?

In this example, I use "Radios + Select + Checkbox" and need them to operate together simultaneously.

JS Bin Link: https://jsbin.com/wegopom/3/edit?js,output

I am targeting `<img>` markers in a Leaflet map based on the:

- **image's "src"** *e.g. img[src$="marker-icon.png"]* (ends with file name)
- **image's "class"** *e.g. img.variation*

Speed on the filter is central as this map will be displaying hundreds and eventually thousands of marker images.

---

**For the Radios,** ("variation" class)... I have a change function:

```
jQuery(document).on("change", ".variation", function() {
```

**For the Select,** ("filterbottler" ID)... I have a second change function:

```
jQuery('#filterbottler').change(function(){
```

**For the checkbox,** ("outages" ID)... I have a third change function:

```
jQuery('#outages').change(function(){
```

It was simple to make two of these change functions work in tandem using a bunch of IF statements and adjoined/chained classes (like img.variation.bottler which would be very slow)... but now that I've added a third filter, it seems like overload and it has now become very hard for me to wrap my brain around every single filtering scenario.

The JS Bin @ https://jsbin.com/wegopom/3/edit?js,output features each of these three filters working independently...

The goal is to get the first three filters (Variation, Bottler, & Outages) to simultaneously work together in the quickest and most efficient way possible. How can I resolve this?

---

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // Filter 1) by Variation
    jQuery(document).on("change", ".variation", function() {
        var bottlerValue = jQuery("#filterbottler").find("option:selected").val();
        var bottlerClass = '.field-ccb-cached__'+bottlerValue;

        // marker groups to be used in exclusionary :not() statements so they aren't affected by the filters... e.g. marker-icon.png & marker-icon-2x.png are "My Location" markers
        var mainMarkers = '[src$="bottler_22px.png"],[src$="marker-icon.png"],[src$="marker-icon-2x.png"]';
        var includeOutageMarkers = '[src$="bottler_22px.png"],[src$="marker-icon.png"],[src$="marker-icon-2x.png"],[src$="cross_22px.png"]';

        if (this.id == "map-filters-show-all") {
            jQuery('.leaflet-marker-pane img:not('+mainMarkers+')').show(500);
        }
        else if (this.id == "map-filters-16oz-cans") {
            jQuery('.leaflet-marker-pane img:not('+includeOutageMarkers+',.field-report-variation__16oz-cans)').hide(500);
            jQuery('.leaflet-marker-pane img.field-report-variation__16oz-cans').show(500);
        } else if (this.id == "map-filters-12oz-cans") {
            jQuery('.leaflet-marker-pane img:not('+includeOutageMarkers+',.field-report-variation__12oz-cans)').hide(500);
            jQuery('.leaflet-marker-pane img.field-report-variation__12oz-cans').show(500);
        } else if (this.id == "map-filters-fountain-surge") {
            jQuery('.leaflet-marker-pane img:not('+includeOutageMarkers+',.field-report-variation__fountain-surge)').hide(500);
            jQuery('.leaflet-marker-pane img.field-report-variation__fountain-surge').show(500);
        } else if (this.id == "map-filters-fountain-surge-red-berry-blast") {
            jQuery('.leaflet-marker-pane img:not('+includeOutageMarkers+',.field-report-variation__fountain-surge-red-berry-blast)').hide(500);
            jQuery('.leaflet-marker-pane img.field-report-variation__fountain-surge-red-berry-blast').show(500);
        }
    });

    // Filter 2) by Bottling Company (select box)
    jQuery('#filterbottler').change(function(){
        var bottlerValue = jQuery("#filterbottler").find("option:selected").val();
        var bottlerClass = '.field-ccb-cached__'+bottlerValue;

        if (bottlerClass != '.field-ccb-cached___none') {
            jQuery('.leaflet-marker-pane img:not([src$="bottler_22px.png"],[src$="marker-icon.png"],[src$="marker-icon-2x.png"],[src$="cross_22px.png"],'+bottlerClass+')').hide(500);
            jQuery('.leaflet-marker-pane img'+bottlerClass).show(500);
        }
        if (bottlerClass === '.field-ccb-cached___none') {
            jQuery('.leaflet-marker-pane img:not([src$="bottler_22px.png"],[src$="marker-icon.png"],[src$="marker-icon-2x.png"])').show(500);
        }

    });

    // Filter 3) Show Outage Reports (checkbox on/off)
    jQuery('#outages').change(function(){
        if(this.checked){
            jQuery('.leaflet-marker-pane img[src$="cross_22px.png"],[src$="exclamation_22px.png"]').fadeToggle(500);
            jQuery.cookie('outagemarkers', true);
        }
        else {
            jQuery('.leaflet-marker-pane img[src$="cross_22px.png"],[src$="exclamation_22px.png"]').fadeToggle(500);
            jQuery.cookie('outagemarkers', false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can use create a snippet?

Comment: Are you able to add more custom classes to the marker icons?

Comment: if I understand correctly. u want to update the view (map) if any one of the filter input has changed right?.have u tried this `$("h2, .class, #id")`

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc My apologies on the delay-- here is a JS Bin w/ everything you'll need! https://jsbin.com/wegopom/edit?js,output

Thank you, this question will award 300 reputation points and I would love to receive your support!

Comment: @SteveO Yes, I can include any field as additional classes, but is this necessary? Feel free to look at the new JS Bin above to understand better what the goal is.

Comment: @ashenmadusanka I don't understand your question or suggestion. Feel free to look at the new JS Bin above to understand better what the goal is.

Comment: Updated fiddle @ https://jsbin.com/wegopom/3/edit?js,output

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc any help?

Comment: @WebMW your jsbin link provided everything I needed to get started on this. I should be done pretty soon with a pretty lightweight example. My first solution will be all in jQuery, and if you **really** want lightweight, it should just as easy to strip out jQuery completely and add the filtering and animations entirely in pure JS and CSS.

Comment: @WebMW Just wanted to point out that in your jsbin for filter #3, both your `if` and `else` conditions have the exact same result. Was this intentional? If so, you may not need the `if`/`else` at all

Comment: @WebMW posted my lightweight solution. Please take a look when you have a chance. I'll be adding my pure JS solution tomorrow as well. Cheers!

Comment: @WebMW please check my updated solution when you have a chance. I've added my pure JS solution which is simpler and much faster than the jQuery solution in terms of performance. I also made several other improvements which have drastically improved the performance of both solutions, including when I assign which variables (before/inside event handler), and how I build an filter by the selectors I dynamically build. Let me know if there is anything else I can do to improve my solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### UPDATE

1. I have updated both my jQuery and pure JS solutions to move all constant variables outside of the event handler to improve performance.
2. I improved the way in which I build the selectors and filters for both. For jQuery, this means using `'*'` as a fallback vaklue when a filter is not active (set to `show-all` or `none`). In pure JS, I use a boolean `false` to "turn off" the filter and then when using `filter()` later, if a filter is set to `false`, I manually set the filter condition to `true` to bypass it.
3. Some selectors we were querying were able to be simplified. For example, rather than querying all select options and then using `find()` or `filter()` to find the one that is `selected` only to get that option's value, I simply get the value of the `<select>` element itself. In jQuery: `bottlerSelect.val()`, and in pure JS: `bottlerSelect.value`.

---

To maximize the performance of your program, it's best to keep all your filters together in one blocks and then filter for all of them. Once we've defined all our desired filters, we can filter all our markers by the filter selectors and save them into a `matchedMarkers` variables. We can then take those that didn't match and save them into a separate `unmatchedMarkers` with this one line: `unmatchedMarkers = allMarkers.not(matchedMarkers);`

All put together, it's actually a very simple and lightweight program, and it could be even more efficient in vanilla JS which I hope to revisit in the next day or two.

### jQuery Solution

CodePen link: https://cdpn.io/e/943560466fc36d61871d01b57739137d

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var allMarkers = $('.leaflet-marker-icon'),
      variationPrefix = 'field-report-variation__',
      bottlerPrefix = 'field-ccb-cached__',
      outagesSelector = ':not([src$="cross_22px.png"],[src$="exclamation_22px.png"])',
      variationInputs = $('input.variation'),
      bottlerSelect = $('#filterbottler'),
      outagesCheckbox = $('#outages');
  $(document).on('change', '.variation, #filterbottler, #outages', function() {
    var variationSelector = '.'+variationPrefix+variationInputs.filter(':checked').attr('id').split('-').slice(2).join('-').toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'-'),
      variationFilter = variationSelector.endsWith('__show-all') ? '*' : variationSelector + ',:not([class*="'+variationPrefix+'"])',
      bottlerSelector = '.'+bottlerPrefix+bottlerSelect.val(),
      bottlerFilter = bottlerSelector.endsWith('___none') ? '*' : bottlerSelector + ',:not([class*="'+bottlerPrefix+'"])',
      outagesFilter = outagesCheckbox.is(':checked') ? '*' : outagesSelector,
      matchedMarkers = allMarkers.filter(variationFilter).filter(bottlerFilter).filter(outagesFilter),
      unmatchedMarkers = allMarkers.not(matchedMarkers);
    matchedMarkers.fadeIn(500);
    unmatchedMarkers.fadeOut(500);
  });
});
```

```css
.leaflet-marker-pane{width:100%;border:1px solid #000}table td{min-width:25px;height:30px;border:1px solid gray;padding:10px}
```

```html
<div class="form-item" id="map-filter-content"> <label style="font-size:18px;">Filter Reports by Variation <i>(must either "Show All" or be a specific variation):</i></label><div class="form-checkboxes"> <input type="radio" value="Show All" name="variation" class="variation" id="map-filters-show-all" checked=""> <label>Show All</label><br> <input type="radio" value="16oz Cans" name="variation" class="variation" id="map-filters-16oz-cans"> <label>16oz Cans</label><br> <input type="radio" value="12oz Cans" name="variation" class="variation" id="map-filters-12oz-cans"> <label>12oz Cans</label><br> <input type="radio" value="Fountain SURGE" name="variation" class="variation" id="map-filters-fountain-surge"> <label>Fountain SURGE</label><br> <input type="radio" value="Fountain SURGE Red Berry Blast" name="variation" class="variation" id="map-filters-fountain-surge-red-berry-blast"> <label>Fountain SURGE Red Berry Blast</label></div><hr style="margin:15px 0 10px 0;"><div class="field-widget-options-select form-wrapper"><div class="control-group form-type-select form-item"> <label style="font-size:18px;">Filter by Bottling Company <i>(must either "Show All" or be a specific bottler):</i></label><div class="controls"> <select id="filterbottler" class="form-select"><option value="_none">- Select All Coca-Cola Bottlers -</option><option value="190">ABARTA</option><option value="191">Aberdeen Coca-Cola</option><option value="192">Ada Coca-Cola</option><option value="193">Atlantic Coca-Cola</option><option value="194">Bemidji Coca-Cola</option><option value="195">Binks Coca-Cola</option><option value="196">Canyon City Coca-Cola</option><option value="197">Cedar City Coca-Cola</option><option value="198">Chesterman Coca-Cola</option><option value="199">Clark</option><option value="200">Coca-Cola Consolidated</option><option value="186">Coca-Cola High Country</option><option value="187">Coca-Cola Southwest</option><option value="177">Coca-Cola UNITED</option><option value="201">Columbus Coca-Cola</option><option value="202">Corinth</option><option value="203">Decatur</option><option value="204">Deming Coca-Cola</option><option value="205">Dickinson Coca-Cola</option><option value="206">Durango Coca-Cola</option><option value="207">Durham Coca-Cola</option><option value="183">Emporia Coca-Cola</option><option value="208">Florida Coca-Cola</option><option value="209">Fort Smith Coca-Cola</option><option value="244">Glasgow Coca-Cola</option><option value="210">Glendive Coca-Cola</option><option value="211">Great Lakes Coca-Cola</option><option value="212">Hancock</option><option value="213">Heartland Coca-Cola</option><option value="214">Hot Springs Coca-Cola</option><option value="215">Huntsville</option><option value="216">Idabel Coca-Cola</option><option value="217">Internation Falls</option><option value="218">Jefferson Coca-Cola</option><option value="219">Ketchikan</option><option value="220">Kokomo Coca-Cola</option><option value="178">Lehrkinds</option><option value="184">Liberty Coca-Cola</option><option value="221">Love Coca-Cola</option><option value="222">Lufkin Coca-Cola</option><option value="223">Macon</option><option value="224">Magnolia Coca-Cola</option><option value="225">Maui</option><option value="226">Meridian</option><option value="227">MiddlesBoro</option><option value="179">Mile High</option><option value="228">Minden Coca-Cola</option><option value="182">Nashville Coca-Cola</option><option value="229">Northern New England</option><option value="230">ODOM</option><option value="231">Orangeburg Coca-Cola</option><option value="232">Ozarks Coca-Cola</option><option value="233">Pulaski Coca-Cola</option><option value="176">Reyes Coca-Cola</option><option value="234">Rock Hill Coca-Cola</option><option value="235">Santa Fe Coca-Cola</option><option value="236">Sitka</option><option value="237">Sooner Coca-Cola</option><option value="185">Swire Coca-Cola</option><option value="181">Timber Country</option><option value="238">Trenton Coca-Cola</option><option value="180">Tullahoma Coca-Cola</option><option value="239">Union City</option><option value="174">Viking Coca-Cola</option><option value="240">Washington Coca-Cola</option><option value="241">Williston Coca-Cola</option><option value="188">Winfield Coca-Cola</option><option value="242">Winona Coca-Cola</option><option value="243">Yakima Coca-Cola</option> </select></div></div></div><hr style="margin:15px 0 10px 0;"><div class="mwcheck"> <input type="checkbox" id="outages" checked> <label>Show Outage Reports <i>(must turn these icons on/off with other filters intact: <img src="https://surgemovement.org/sites/all/themes/surgemovement/images/ip_geoloc_custom_markers/exclamation_22px.png"> & <img src="https://surgemovement.org/sites/all/themes/surgemovement/images/ip_geoloc_custom_markers/cross_22px.png">)</i></label></div></div><hr><div class="leaflet-marker-pane"><table><tr><td><img src="https://surgemovement.org/sites/all/themes/surgemovement/images/ip_geoloc_custom_markers/check_22px.png" class="leaflet-marker-icon tag-inside-marker field-report-variation__16oz-cans field-ccb-cached__190"></td><td> < Has Class "field-report-variation__16oz-cans" <b>(16oz Cans)</b><br> < Has Class "field-ccb-cached__190" <b>("ABARTA" Bottling Company)</b></td></tr><tr><td><img src="https://surgemovement.org/sites/all/themes/surgemovement/images/ip_geoloc_custom_markers/check_22px.png" class="leaflet-marker-icon tag-inside-marker field-report-variation__12oz-cans field-ccb-cached__190"></td><td> < Has Class "field-report-variation__12oz-cans" <b>(12oz Cans)</b><br> < Has Class "field-ccb-cached__190" <b>("ABARTA" Bottling Company)</b></td></tr><tr><td><img src="https://surgemovement.org/sites/all/themes/surgemovement/images/ip_geoloc_custom_markers/check_22px.png" class="leaflet-marker-icon tag-inside-marker field-report-variation__12oz-cans field-ccb-cached__191"></td><td> < Has Class "field-report-variation__12oz-cans" <b>(12oz Cans)</b><br> < Has Class "field-ccb-cached__191" <b>("Aberdeen Coca-Cola" Bottling Company)</b></td></tr><tr><td><img src="https://surgemovement.org/sites/all/themes/surgemovement/images/ip_geoloc_custom_markers/exclamation_22px.png" class="leaflet-marker-icon tag-inside-marker field-report-variation__16oz-cans field-ccb-cached__190"></td><td> < Has Class "field-report-variation__16oz-cans" <b>(16oz Cans)</b><br> < Has Class "field-ccb-cached__190" <b>("ABARTA Coca-Cola" Bottling Company)</b></td></tr><tr><td><img src="https://surgemovement.org/sites/all/themes/surgemovement/images/ip_geoloc_custom_markers/exclamation_22px.png" class="leaflet-marker-icon tag-inside-marker field-report-variation__16oz-cans field-ccb-cached__191"></td><td> < Has Class "field-report-variation__16oz-cans" <b>(16oz Cans)</b><br> < Has Class "field-ccb-cached__191" <b>("Aberdeen Coca-Cola" Bottling Company)</b></td></tr><tr><td><img src="https://surgemovement.org/sites/all/themes/surgemovement/images/ip_geoloc_custom_markers/exclamation_22px.png" class="leaflet-marker-icon tag-inside-marker field-report-variation__12oz-cans field-ccb-cached__191"></td><td> < Has Class "field-report-variation__12oz-cans" <b>(12oz Cans)</b><br> < Has Class "field-ccb-cached__191" <b>("Aberdeen Coca-Cola" Bottling Company)</b></td></tr><tr><td><img src="https://surgemovement.org/sites/all/themes/surgemovement/images/ip_geoloc_custom_markers/cross_22px.png" class="leaflet-marker-icon tag-inside-marker field-ccb-cached__191"></td><td> < Has Class "field-ccb-cached__191" <b>("Aberdeen Coca-Cola" Bottling Company)</b> <br><br>This always shows unless:<br>1) "Show Outage Reports" is deselected... or <br>2) Another bottling company (e.g. ABARTA is selected)<br></td></tr></table></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
```

### Pure JavaScript Solution

CodePen link: https://cdpn.io/e/d9e89a278a7bb190841c19f53c376033

This pure vanilla JavaScript solution is even simpler than the jQuery solution, and it will increase performance quite a bit if you can exclude jQuery from this project altogether and stick to pure JS. No need to wait for the page to be fully loaded. Just run your JavaScript right after the HTML content and everything will work as expected. This also allows for greater flexibility in our filtering methods. Rather than running three filter functions back-to-back, we can run all our conditions in one single filter method and immediately either fade in or out the associated marker element. Also to improve performance, instead of relying on JavaScript to animate the fading transition, I created two simple states in the CSS, the default state (`opacity: 1`), and a filtered state denoted by the class `.filtered`. All the fading in and out takes place completed in the CSS with a simple CSS transition determined by whether or not the `.filtered` class is applied.

Here it is in pure JavaScript:

```js
const allMarkers = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.leaflet-marker-icon')),
      variationPrefix = 'field-report-variation__',
      bottlerPrefix = 'field-ccb-cached__',
      outagesSelector = ':not([src$="cross_22px.png"],[src$="exclamation_22px.png"])',
      variationInputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input.variation')),
      bottlerSelect = document.getElementById('filterbottler'),
      outagesCheckbox = document.getElementById('outages');
document.addEventListener('change', e => {
  if (e.target?.matches('.variation, #filterbottler, #outages')) {
    const variationSelector = '.'+variationPrefix+variationInputs.filter(input => input.checked)[0].id.split('-').slice(2).join('-').toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'-'),
          variationFilter = variationSelector.endsWith('__show-all') ? false : variationSelector + ',:not([class*="'+variationPrefix+'"])',
          bottlerSelector = '.'+bottlerPrefix+bottlerSelect.value,
          bottlerFilter = bottlerSelector.endsWith('___none') ? false : bottlerSelector + ',:not([class*="'+bottlerPrefix+'"])',
          outagesFilter = outagesCheckbox.checked ? false : outagesSelector;
    allMarkers.forEach(marker => ((variationFilter ? marker.matches(variationFilter) : true) && (bottlerFilter ? marker.matches(bottlerFilter) : true) && (outagesFilter ? marker.matches(outagesFilter) : true)) ? marker.classList.remove('filtered') : marker.classList.add('filtered'));
  }
});
```

```css
.leaflet-marker-pane{width:100%;border:1px solid #000}table td{min-width:25px;height:30px;border:1px solid gray;padding:10px}

.leaflet-marker-icon {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-out;
}
.leaflet-marker-icon.filtered {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-item" id="map-filter-content"> <label style="font-size:18px;">Filter Reports by Variation <i>(must either "Show All" or be a specific variation):</i></label><div class="form-checkboxes"> <input type="radio" value="Show All" name="variation" class="variation" id="map-filters-show-all" checked=""> <label>Show All</label><br> <input type="radio" value="16oz Cans" name="variation" class="variation" id="map-filters-16oz-cans"> <label>16oz Cans</label><br> <input type="radio" value="12oz Cans" name="variation" class="variation" id="map-filters-12oz-cans"> <label>12oz Cans</label><br> <input type="radio" value="Fountain SURGE" name="variation" class="variation" id="map-filters-fountain-surge"> <label>Fountain SURGE</label><br> <input type="radio" value="Fountain SURGE Red Berry Blast" name="variation" class="variation" id="map-filters-fountain-surge-red-berry-blast"> <label>Fountain SURGE Red Berry Blast</label></div><hr style="margin:15px 0 10px 0;"><div class="field-widget-options-select form-wrapper"><div class="control-group form-type-select form-item"> <label style="font-size:18px;">Filter by Bottling Company <i>(must either "Show All" or be a specific bottler):</i></label><div class="controls"> <select id="filterbottler" class="form-select"><option value="_none">- Select All Coca-Cola Bottlers -</option><option value="190">ABARTA</option><option value="191">Aberdeen Coca-Cola</option><option value="192">Ada Coca-Cola</option><option value="193">Atlantic Coca-Cola</option><option value="194">Bemidji Coca-Cola</option><option value="195">Binks Coca-Cola</option><option value="196">Canyon City Coca-Cola</option><option value="197">Cedar City Coca-Cola</option><option value="198">Chesterman Coca-Cola</option><option value="199">Clark</option><option value="200">Coca-Cola Consolidated</option><option value="186">Coca-Cola High Country</option><option value="187">Coca-Cola Southwest</option><option value="177">Coca-Cola UNITED</option><option value="201">Columbus Coca-Cola</option><option value="202">Corinth</option><option value="203">Decatur</option><option value="204">Deming Coca-Cola</option><option value="205">Dickinson Coca-Cola</option><option value="206">Durango Coca-Cola</option><option value="207">Durham Coca-Cola</option><option value="183">Emporia Coca-Cola</option><option value="208">Florida Coca-Cola</option><option value="209">Fort Smith Coca-Cola</option><option value="244">Glasgow Coca-Cola</option><option value="210">Glendive Coca-Cola</option><option value="211">Great Lakes Coca-Cola</option><option value="212">Hancock</option><option value="213">Heartland Coca-Cola</option><option value="214">Hot Springs Coca-Cola</option><option value="215">Huntsville</option><option value="216">Idabel Coca-Cola</option><option value="217">Internation Falls</option><option value="218">Jefferson Coca-Cola</option><option value="219">Ketchikan</option><option value="220">Kokomo Coca-Cola</option><option value="178">Lehrkinds</option><option value="184">Liberty Coca-Cola</option><option value="221">Love Coca-Cola</option><option value="222">Lufkin Coca-Cola</option><option value="223">Macon</option><option value="224">Magnolia Coca-Cola</option><option value="225">Maui</option><option value="226">Meridian</option><option value="227">MiddlesBoro</option><option value="179">Mile High</option><option value="228">Minden Coca-Cola</option><option value="182">Nashville Coca-Cola</option><option value="229">Northern New England</option><option value="230">ODOM</option><option value="231">Orangeburg Coca-Cola</option><option value="232">Ozarks Coca-Cola</option><option value="233">Pulaski Coca-Cola</option><option value="176">Reyes Coca-Cola</option><option value="234">Rock Hill Coca-Cola</option><option value="235">Santa Fe Coca-Cola</option><option value="236">Sitka</option><option value="237">Sooner Coca-Cola</option><option value="185">Swire Coca-Cola</option><option value="181">Timber Country</option><option value="238">Trenton Coca-Cola</option><option value="180">Tullahoma Coca-Cola</option><option value="239">Union City</option><option value="174">Viking Coca-Cola</option><option value="240">Washington Coca-Cola</option><option value="241">Williston Coca-Cola</option><option value="188">Winfield Coca-Cola</option><option value="242">Winona Coca-Cola</option><option value="243">Yakima Coca-Cola</option> </select></div></div></div><hr style="margin:15px 0 10px 0;"><div class="mwcheck"> <input type="checkbox" id="outages" checked> <label>Show Outage Reports <i>(must turn these icons on/off with other filters intact: <img src="https://surgemovement.org/sites/all/themes/surgemovement/images/ip_geoloc_custom_markers/exclamation_22px.png"> & <img src="https://surgemovement.org/sites/all/themes/surgemovement/images/ip_geoloc_custom_markers/cross_22px.png">)</i></label></div></div><hr><div class="leaflet-marker-pane"><table><tr><td><img src="https://surgemovement.org/sites/all/themes/surgemovement/images/ip_geoloc_custom_markers/check_22px.png" class="leaflet-marker-icon tag-inside-marker field-report-variation__16oz-cans field-ccb-cached__190"></td><td> < Has Class "field-report-variation__16oz-cans" <b>(16oz Cans)</b><br> < Has Class "field-ccb-cached__190" <b>("ABARTA" Bottling Company)</b></td></tr><tr><td><img src="https://surgemovement.org/sites/all/themes/surgemovement/images/ip_geoloc_custom_markers/check_22px.png" class="leaflet-marker-icon tag-inside-marker field-report-variation__12oz-cans field-ccb-cached__190"></td><td> < Has Class "field-report-variation__12oz-cans" <b>(12oz Cans)</b><br> < Has Class "field-ccb-cached__190" <b>("ABARTA" Bottling Company)</b></td></tr><tr><td><img src="https://surgemovement.org/sites/all/themes/surgemovement/images/ip_geoloc_custom_markers/check_22px.png" class="leaflet-marker-icon tag-inside-marker field-report-variation__12oz-cans field-ccb-cached__191"></td><td> < Has Class "field-report-variation__12oz-cans" <b>(12oz Cans)</b><br> < Has Class "field-ccb-cached__191" <b>("Aberdeen Coca-Cola" Bottling Company)</b></td></tr><tr><td><img src="https://surgemovement.org/sites/all/themes/surgemovement/images/ip_geoloc_custom_markers/exclamation_22px.png" class="leaflet-marker-icon tag-inside-marker field-report-variation__16oz-cans field-ccb-cached__190"></td><td> < Has Class "field-report-variation__16oz-cans" <b>(16oz Cans)</b><br> < Has Class "field-ccb-cached__190" <b>("ABARTA Coca-Cola" Bottling Company)</b></td></tr><tr><td><img src="https://surgemovement.org/sites/all/themes/surgemovement/images/ip_geoloc_custom_markers/exclamation_22px.png" class="leaflet-marker-icon tag-inside-marker field-report-variation__16oz-cans field-ccb-cached__191"></td><td> < Has Class "field-report-variation__16oz-cans" <b>(16oz Cans)</b><br> < Has Class "field-ccb-cached__191" <b>("Aberdeen Coca-Cola" Bottling Company)</b></td></tr><tr><td><img src="https://surgemovement.org/sites/all/themes/surgemovement/images/ip_geoloc_custom_markers/exclamation_22px.png" class="leaflet-marker-icon tag-inside-marker field-report-variation__12oz-cans field-ccb-cached__191"></td><td> < Has Class "field-report-variation__12oz-cans" <b>(12oz Cans)</b><br> < Has Class "field-ccb-cached__191" <b>("Aberdeen Coca-Cola" Bottling Company)</b></td></tr><tr><td><img src="https://surgemovement.org/sites/all/themes/surgemovement/images/ip_geoloc_custom_markers/cross_22px.png" class="leaflet-marker-icon tag-inside-marker field-ccb-cached__191"></td><td> < Has Class "field-ccb-cached__191" <b>("Aberdeen Coca-Cola" Bottling Company)</b> <br><br>This always shows unless:<br>1) "Show Outage Reports" is deselected... or <br>2) Another bottling company (e.g. ABARTA is selected)<br></td></tr></table></div>
```

Comment: This is amazing! Easy to understand, flawless in my initial tests and like you said... lightweight! I also tested the last two variations and your split/slice/lowercase selector nailed it. Looking forward to your pure JavaScript solution and I will follow up shortly. Well done Brandon!

Comment: @WebMW, note that there is an initial selection of the entire set of markers, and then requerying it multiple times (you can actually merge them into a single query for showing and a single one for hiding, which is what I did in my answer). Whatever you choose, you might want to benchmark.

Comment: I think the red cross is not visible when it should (e.g., just selecting 16oz shouldn't make it hidden).

Comment: @OfirD Not sure what you're referring to in your first comment. I did only use one query for the markers, and then I filter that query, once for matched markers, and once for unmatched. This is much faster than querying all entire marker set once for each set (matched vs. unmatched). I highly encouraging benchmarking as well, WebMW.

Comment: @WebMW OfirD made a good call-out in his second comment. I misunderstood how items should display when they don't include a variation class. So it should only filter by variation when at least one variation class is present, so filtering by variation should not filter the final item. I'll make this change now.

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell, the first query `$('.leaflet-marker-icon')` gets all markers on page.  This may not be ideal in case of large amount of markers. The next triple `filter` chaining may also be optimized if turned into a single filter query.

Comment: @OfirD this should actually be faster than your example. In order to effectively show/hide all markers correctly with each time, we do need to query all markers. Your solution actually performs 2 separate queries with your `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` line. My solution reduces this to a single query  and then filters that query appropriately, which is much simpler.

Comment: @WebMW per OfirD's concern about performance here, my solution should actually maximize performance. Also, if you will have all markers visible on page load, rather than querying all markers every time a change is made, which is what both by solution and OfirD's both do, we can store that `allMarkers` variable outside the event handler altogether so we only query all markers once and then filter that with the `fadeIn`/`fadeOut` methods only when needed. Also, if you will have additional markers load in dynamically later via AJAX, we can always re-query the `allMarkers` variable with that event

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell, I don't think two filtering queries (my code) can be slower than one unfiltering query+5 additional sub queries (yours), I think it's vice versa, but again, that's for benchmarking to decide.

Comment: @OfirD yes, it would be slower. When you query a new jQuery object using `$('…')` you are querying the entire document, similar to `document.querySelectorAll('…')`. When you filter/unfilter a jQuery object you are only querying under that object similar to `element.querySelectorAll('…')` which is much quicker.

Comment: @WebMW I've just made a few changes to my jQuery solution— (#1) moving the markers query to a single query **before** the event handler which should drastically improve performance, and (#2, #3) added a negation-check for both the variation and bottling filters, which will ensure we only filter out markers for both those attributes when they have at least one class with the relevant prefix `field-report-variation__` or `field-ccb-cached__`. This way, by default markers missing either a variation or bottling class, like the last `cross_22px` marker only filter for classes it contains.

Comment: @WebMW I've just pushed a big update that moves all element querying outside of the event handler for a significant performance improvement. Instead of querying in the event handler, we simply filter the already-queried jQuery objects `variationInputs` and `bottlerOptions` for their `:checked` and `:selected` statuses.

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell, take a look at [this performance example](https://jsfiddle.net/wn0zx5Lm/) I quickly made. It's very, very limited in what it tests, but proves my point.

Comment: @OfirD your benchmark test isn't accurate. You have a space where one is not needed in test1's selector. Also, we are not comparing querying by selector vs. filter as your benchmark does. We are comparing repeated document querying vs filtering a jQuery object. Once a jQuery object exists, it is reasonably quicker to filter that object than to query the document again. See my benchmark example with your same code, with my code as test1: https://jsfiddle.net/Lskbh0ot/ On my system, it actually appears according to the benchmark that the winner goes back and forth. It's too close to even tell.

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell, that space in my test doesn't change anything in terms of performance, and your second test method is something neither of our codes do.

Comment: @OfirD Yes, it is. That's precisely what I'm saying. The `filter()` method filters the jQuery object to whichever elements it contains that match the filter selector, but your test with a space was looking at descendants, not the actual elements at hand.

Comment: @OfirD also, would you mind if we reserved the comment under my post for questions from the OP? You're essentially using this area under my post to challenge my solution and in turn clogging up my post's comments area, making it more difficult for me to support the needs of the OP. If you would like to continue this discussion, please create a private chat room for the two of us and invite me to it.

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell, it's not. go ahead and erase that space in my test, then run it, you'll see no difference in performance. I think it's an important discussion, but I'll leave it for now (also, feel free to move this discussion to chat).

Comment: To both of you, I enjoyed this discussion and would like to thank each of you for getting down to this degree of detail, even with benchmarking. I am thankful that OfirD's advice could improve what already appeared to my novice brain as a great solution. I think it's important we are able to have these discussions and challenge each other especially when the focus is achieving the absolute best performance. I think both of these answers do a great job but this one, especially with the support of OfirD, seems flawless. Thank each of you for your time on this and I hope it will help others!

Comment: Thank you both as well. Still a bit of a discussion left to be had here on effective benchmarking which other answers capitalized on, but I do believe through all the back and forth, we managed to produce a highly refined solution to the question asked.

Comment: @WebMW also one more small update for performance purposes. I swapped `includes()` for `endsWith()` which is shown to be faster as the function does not need to search the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the fastest strategy (in terms of performance) to filter a
> combination of different type filters in jQuery?

I think it's safe to say that the less conditions and the less selectors, the better performance (though we can't actually know without benchmarking).

To achieve this goal, you can work with classes only.

The following code is based on your [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/wegopom/3/edit?output), and it behaves in the following ways:

1. It introduces three new classes: `variation`, `bottler`, `outage`.
2. It utilizes filter-controllers values as class names parts (e.g., bottler's value `190` is used to select the class `bottler-190`).
3. When two or more filters are selected (e.g., both variation and bottler), the intersection of those filters should be displayed.

   - That's an important one. The reason your current code is buggy in some cases is that you handle each filter separately on its own handler, while actually, you must always consider all existing filters, on any `change` event.
4. It changes and shortens existing class names for convenience, better readbility, and easier maintenance.

   - For example, `field-report-variation__12oz-cans` is replaced with 'variation-12oz'.
5. For better readability of this answer, I took the freedom to remove:
   a. Unused classes (e.g., `tag-inside-marker`).
   b. Unused elements (e.g., `Fountain SURGE` radio button).
   Of course, they can be just returned back and used as needed.

Let me first show you the code, and I'll then lay out some notes and assumptions:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.variation, #bottler, #outage').change(function () {
      filter();
  });
});

const baseSelector = ".leaflet-marker-icon";

function filter() {
  // controllers values
  const variation = $('input[name="variation"]:checked')[0].id;
  const bottler = $('#bottler').val();
  const outage = $('#outage').is(':checked'); 

  // selectors to show
  let variationSelector = variation.includes('all') ? '.variation' : '.' + variation;
  let bottlerSelector = bottler.includes('all') ? '.bottler' : '.bottler-' + bottler;
  let outageSelector = outage ? '.outage' : '' ;
  // show
  $(`${baseSelector}${variationSelector}${bottlerSelector}\
     ${outageSelector ? ',' + baseSelector + outageSelector : ''}`).fadeIn(500);

  // selectors to hide
  variationSelector = variationSelector == '.variation' ? '' : variationSelector;
  bottlerSelector = bottlerSelector == '.bottler' ? '' : bottlerSelector;
  outageSelector = outage ? '' : '.outage'; 
  const any = bottlerSelector || variationSelector;
  // hide
  $(`${ any ? `${baseSelector}:not(${[bottlerSelector,variationSelector].filter(n => n).join('')})` : '' }\
     ${outageSelector ? (any ? ',' : '') + baseSelector + outageSelector : ''}`).fadeOut(500);

}
```

```css
table td {
  min-width:25px;
  height:30px;
  border:1px solid gray;
  padding:10px;
}
.leaflet-marker-pane {
  width:200px
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<div class="form-item" id="map-filter-content">
<label style="font-size:18px;">Filter Reports by Variation <i>(must either "Show All" or be a specific variation):</i></label>
<div class="form-checkboxes">
  <input id="variation-all" type="radio" value="Show All" name="variation" class="variation" checked="">
  <label>Show All</label><br>
  <input id="variation-16oz" type="radio" value="16oz Cans" name="variation" class="variation">
  <label>16oz Cans</label><br>
  <input id="variation-12oz" type="radio" value="12oz Cans" name="variation" class="variation">
  <label>12oz Cans</label><br>
</div>
<hr style="margin:15px 0 10px 0;">
<div class="field-widget-options-select form-wrapper">
  <div class="control-group form-type-select form-item">
    <label style="font-size:18px;">Filter by Bottling Company <i>(must either "Show All" or be a specific bottler):</i></label>
    <div class="controls">
      <select id="bottler" class="form-select">
        <option value="all">- Select All Coca-Cola Bottlers -</option>
        <option value="190">ABARTA</option>
        <option value="191">Aberdeen Coca-Cola</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr style="margin:15px 0 10px 0;">
<div class="mwcheck">
  <input type="checkbox" id="outage" checked>
  <label>Show Outage Reports <i>(must turn these icons on/off with other filters intact: <img src="https://surgemovement.org/sites/all/themes/surgemovement/images/ip_geoloc_custom_markers/exclamation_22px.png"> & <img src="https://surgemovement.org/sites/all/themes/surgemovement/images/ip_geoloc_custom_markers/cross_22px.png">)</i></label></div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="leaflet-marker-pane">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="https://surgemovement.org/sites/all/themes/surgemovement/images/ip_geoloc_custom_markers/check_22px.png" 
        class="leaflet-marker-icon variation variation-16oz bottler bottler-190">
      </td>
      <td>
        Has class "variation-16oz" <b>(16oz Cans)</b><br>
        Has class "bottler-190" <b>("ABARTA" Bottling Company)</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="https://surgemovement.org/sites/all/themes/surgemovement/images/ip_geoloc_custom_markers/check_22px.png" 
      class="leaflet-marker-icon variation variation-12oz bottler bottler-190">
      </td>
      <td>
        Has class "variation-12oz" <b>(12oz Cans)</b><br>
        Has class "bottler-190" <b>("ABARTA" Bottling Company)</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="https://surgemovement.org/sites/all/themes/surgemovement/images/ip_geoloc_custom_markers/check_22px.png" 
        class="leaflet-marker-icon variation variation-12oz bottler bottler-191">
      </td>
      <td>
        Has Class "variation-12oz" <b>(12oz Cans)</b><br>
        Has class "bottler-191" <b>("Aberdeen Coca-Cola")</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="https://surgemovement.org/sites/all/themes/surgemovement/images/ip_geoloc_custom_markers/exclamation_22px.png" 
             class="leaflet-marker-icon variation variation-16oz bottler bottler-190 outage">
      </td>
      <td>
        Has class "variation-16oz" <b>(16oz Cans)</b><br>
        Has class "bottler-190" <b>("ABARTA" Bottling Company)</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="https://surgemovement.org/sites/all/themes/surgemovement/images/ip_geoloc_custom_markers/exclamation_22px.png" 
      class="leaflet-marker-icon variation variation-16oz bottler bottler-191 outage">
      </td>
      <td>
        Has class "variation-16oz" <b>(16oz Cans)</b><br>
        Has class "bottler-191" <b>("Aberdeen Coca-Cola")</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="https://surgemovement.org/sites/all/themes/surgemovement/images/ip_geoloc_custom_markers/exclamation_22px.png" 
        class="leaflet-marker-icon variation variation-12oz bottler bottler-191 outage">
      </td>
      <td>
        Has Class "variation-12oz" <b>(12oz Cans)</b><br>
        Has Class "bottler-191" <b>("Aberdeen Coca-Cola")</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
      <img src="https://surgemovement.org/sites/all/themes/surgemovement/images/ip_geoloc_custom_markers/cross_22px.png" 
      class="leaflet-marker-icon variation variation-16oz variation-12oz bottler bottler-191 outage"></td>
      <td>
        Has Class "bottler-191" <b>("Aberdeen Coca-Cola")</b>
        <br><br>
        This always shows unless:<br>
        1) "Show Outage Reports" is deselected <br>
        2) Another bottling company (e.g. ABARTA is selected)<br>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you! Allow me to continue studying your code... I did notice one error in the meantime-- to reproduce, have both filters set to "Show All" and then deselect Show Outages. P.S. is it okay to preserve the animation on the show() & hide()?

Comment: Thanks OfirD! + I tried adding 500ms back in on the show() & hide() animations and it looks like they pop in & out so maybe it's not that easy, but I'm probably doing it wrong.

Comment: @WebMW, the error is now fixed, and I also added the 500ms.

Comment: Thank you @OfirD-- this is almost perfect! Not the end of the world, but the 500ms causes the icons to appear momentarily when being hidden. Is there any easy fix to this?

Comment: @WebMW, I'm not really sure what you experience as I seem to not see that, but you can replace `show` with `fadeIn` and `hide` with `fadeOut`.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you few rules that may help you optimize performance in the best way, cause every problem has its own solution.

**1. Event Listeners**
The best way to boost event listeners performance is to use delegation, and for so many filters triggers I would suggest you wrap them all under one parent and fire changes based on the triggering child

You can read more [here](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Example:

```
// Attach a delegated event handler with a more refined selector
$( "#list" ).on( "click", "a[href^='http']", function( event ) {
    $( this ).attr( "target", "_blank" );
});
```

---

**2. Animations**

I saw you are using jQuery `show` and `hide`, for best performance you may want to read this [article](https://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/) and specially the [benchmarking](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/srfxA) part.

To see real difference try with large number of dots.

Conclusion might be that just adding and removing a class (that has transitions) can be much faster than using jQuery animations

---

**3. Selectors**
This is the most effective part when you run this on a large number of dom elements, and for this you can refer to this [article](https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/), or this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34100018/selector-for-best-performance-in-jquery)

---

**4. Implementation**
Using classes to describe data field, may not be the best idea. Classes are used to decide how things should be painted, look like, or animate .. etc, but not for example to define if the product is Cocacola, or Pepsi .. a vehicle or a chair.

For this reason try to use **[data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)** attribute (in jQuery: [**data**](https://api.jquery.com/data/))

This will not only make your code more readable, but will make your logic more easier to write, and your selectors more performant.

---

Final thoughts:
Benchmarking is always the best way to tell how things can perform, you can always use:

- **[JSbenchme](https://jsbench.me/)**
- **[JSBen.ch](https://jsben.ch/)**

and unfortunately the best of them `jsperf` is no longer available, but these should do the job.